# Will ArcGIS 10 run on Windows 8?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, windows-8, system-requirements

I have access to ArcGIS 10 through university, however my laptop runs Windows 8.  I have checked the requirements and they have listed the previous operating systems (excluding 8)

http://resources.arcgis.com/content/arcgisdesktop/10.0/arcgis-desktop-system-requirements

Will it run? If not, are there any ways round this (other than buying Arc 10.1 or installing an older operating system)?

Comment: I'm going to download SP1 but I found problems running Windows 8 with 10.1 without it. Even minor things like changing labels in properties can cause the program to crash...

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question. Please open a new question detailing your issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

from [ArcGIS Resource Center Blog](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/11/01/arcgis-10-1-and-windows-8/).

> Windows 8 and Windows 2012 Server are now officially supported
>   starting at ArcGIS 10.1 SP1

and from [ArcGIS 10.1 System Requirements](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/system-requirements/10.1/index.html#/ArcGIS_10_1_for_Desktop/015100000002000000/)

> Windows Server 2012 Standard, and Datacenter (64-bit [EM64T]) ***
>
> Windows 8 Basic, Professional and Enterprise (32-bit and 64-bit
>   [EM64T])***

i hope it helps you...

Answer (score 1):

**Windows 8** is backwards compatible, it means the applications running on **Windows 7** must be able to run on **Windows 8**. Therefore it shouldn't throw any problem.

Comment: Setting aside ArcGIS, Microsoft is not guaranteeing that all Win7 applications will run on Windows 8: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsdeveloperpreviewgeneral/thread/d4850eb7-5fb2-45b6-9e89-cd13056c4797

Comment: @mkennedy I Agree, but I'm pretty sure there's no problem with ArcGIS

Answer (score 1):

The [Windows 8 Compatibility Center](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/compatibility/win8/CompatCenter/Home) shows that it works. It's powered by people who used the Windows 8 release preview. I was such a user and has no problems with 10.1 (prior to SP1). Although the Windows 8 metro interface takes some getting used to, I don't believe it's the best OS for power users, but to answer you question, **yes** it does work.

Follow this link to the ArcGIS Windows 8 Compatibility search: [ArcGIS Windows 8 Compatibility](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/compatibility/win8/CompatCenter/ProductViewerWithDefaultFilters?TempOsid=win8&Locale=en-ca&TextSearch=arcgis&Type=Both&CurrentPage=0&TotalPages=1&ShowCriteria=0&SortCriteria=Relevance&Compatibility=Unknown&LastRequested=14).